# how to redirect to newer version of a linux library if two or more older versions of that library are found?

Tags: linux, debian, glib

I downloaded the latest version of libglib2.0 2.76.3 and installed it from source.

However, pkg-config finds an older version of glib when i try to install some programs.
What I must do?

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/lib:/usr/lib:/usr/local/include/glib-2.0/:/usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/;

sudo make clean 
sudo ldconfig 

sudo ./configure PKG_CONFIG_PATH=$PKG_CONFIG_PATH:/usr/local/lib:/usr/lib:/usr/local/include/glib-2.0/:/usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/;
```

```
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 12 (bookworm)
Release:    12
Codename:   bookworm
```

```
checking for GLIB - version >= 2.0.3... 
*** ''pkg-config --modversion glib-2.0' returned 2.76.3, but GLIB (2.74.6) but GLIB (2.74.6)
*** was found! If pkg-config was correct, then it is best
*** to remove the old version of GLib. You may also be able to fix the error
*** by modifying your LD_LIBRARY_PATH enviroment variable, or by editing
*** /etc/ld.so.conf. Make sure you have run ldconfig if that is
*** required on your system.
*** If pkg-config was wrong, set the environment variable PKG_CONFIG_PATH
*** to point to the correct configuration files
```

```
~/_PKGS/glib-2.76.3$ sudo ninja -C _build install 
(some lines...)
Installing /_PKGS/glib-2.76.3/glib/gdir.h to /usr/local/include/glib-2.0/glib
Installing symlink pointing to libglib-2.0.so.0 to /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so
```

```
 dpkg -l | grep libglib2.*
ii  libglib2.0-0:amd64                                          2.74.6-2                                                    amd64        GLib library of C routines
ii  libglib2.0-0:i386                                           2.74.6-2                                                    i386         GLib library of C routines
ii  libglib2.0-bin                                              2.74.6-2                                                    amd64        Programs for the GLib library
ii  libglib2.0-cil                                              2.12.45-0xamarin19+ubuntu1804b1                             amd64        CLI binding for the GLib utility library 2.12
ii  libglib2.0-cil-dev                                          2.12.45-0xamarin19+ubuntu1804b1                             amd64        CLI binding for the GLib utility library 2.12
ii  libglib2.0-data                                             2.74.6-2                                                    all          Common files for GLib library
ii  libglib2.0-dev:amd64                                        2.74.6-2                                                    amd64        Development files for the GLib library
ii  libglib2.0-dev-bin                                          2.74.6-2                                                    amd64        Development utilities for the GLib library
ii  libglib2.0-doc                                              2.74.6-2                                                    all          Documentation files for the GLib library
ii  libglib2.0-tests                                            2.74.6-2                                                    amd64        GLib library of C routines - installed tests
```

```
pkg-config --debug --modversion glib-2.0
libpkgconf/dependency.c:115 [add_or_replace_dependency_node]: added dependency [glib-2.0] to list @0x7fff61922eb8; flags=0
libpkgconf/pkg.c:1562 [pkgconf_pkg_traverse]: virtual:world: level 2000
libpkgconf/pkg.c:1577 [pkgconf_pkg_traverse]: virtual:world: walking requires list
libpkgconf/pkg.c:1343 [pkgconf_pkg_verify_dependency]: trying to verify dependency: glib-2.0
libpkgconf/pkg.c:730 [pkgconf_pkg_find]: looking for: glib-2.0
libpkgconf/cache.c:62 [pkgconf_cache_lookup]: miss: glib-2.0
libpkgconf/pkg.c:568 [pkgconf_pkg_try_specific_path]: trying path: /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ for glib-2.0
libpkgconf/pkg.c:568 [pkgconf_pkg_try_specific_path]: trying path: /usr/local/lib for glib-2.0
libpkgconf/pkg.c:568 [pkgconf_pkg_try_specific_path]: trying path: /usr/lib for glib-2.0
libpkgconf/pkg.c:568 [pkgconf_pkg_try_specific_path]: trying path: /usr/local/include/glib-2.0/ for glib-2.0
libpkgconf/pkg.c:568 [pkgconf_pkg_try_specific_path]: trying path: /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig for glib-2.0
libpkgconf/pkg.c:582 [pkgconf_pkg_try_specific_path]: found: /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/glib-2.0.pc
libpkgconf/tuple.c:189 [pkgconf_tuple_add]: adding tuple to @0x561c35dcaaa8: pcfiledir => /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig (parsed? 1)
libpkgconf/tuple.c:189 [pkgconf_tuple_add]: adding tuple to @0x561c35dcaaa8: prefix => /usr/local (parsed? 1)
libpkgconf/tuple.c:189 [pkgconf_tuple_add]: adding tuple to @0x561c35dcaaa8: includedir => ${prefix}/include (parsed? 1)
libpkgconf/tuple.c:296 [pkgconf_tuple_parse]: lookup tuple prefix
libpkgconf/tuple.c:189 [pkgconf_tuple_add]: adding tuple to @0x561c35dcaaa8: libdir => ${prefix}/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu (parsed? 1)
libpkgconf/tuple.c:296 [pkgconf_tuple_parse]: lookup tuple prefix
libpkgconf/tuple.c:189 [pkgconf_tuple_add]: adding tuple to @0x561c35dcaaa8: bindir => ${prefix}/bin (parsed? 1)
libpkgconf/tuple.c:296 [pkgconf_tuple_parse]: lookup tuple prefix
libpkgconf/tuple.c:189 [pkgconf_tuple_add]: adding tuple to @0x561c35dcaaa8: glib_genmarshal => ${bindir}/glib-genmarshal (parsed? 1)
libpkgconf/tuple.c:296 [pkgconf_tuple_parse]: lookup tuple bindir
libpkgconf/tuple.c:189 [pkgconf_tuple_add]: adding tuple to @0x561c35dcaaa8: gobject_query => ${bindir}/gobject-query (parsed? 1)
libpkgconf/tuple.c:296 [pkgconf_tuple_parse]: lookup tuple bindir
libpkgconf/tuple.c:189 [pkgconf_tuple_add]: adding tuple to @0x561c35dcaaa8: glib_mkenums => ${bindir}/glib-mkenums (parsed? 1)
libpkgconf/tuple.c:296 [pkgconf_tuple_parse]: lookup tuple bindir
libpkgconf/dependency.c:115 [add_or_replace_dependency_node]: added dependency [libpcre2-8 >= 10.32] to list @0x561c35dcaa60; flags=0
libpkgconf/tuple.c:296 [pkgconf_tuple_parse]: lookup tuple libdir
libpkgconf/fragment.c:676 [pkgconf_fragment_parse]: post-subst: [-L${libdir} -lglib-2.0] -> [-L/usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lglib-2.0]
libpkgconf/fragment.c:147 [pkgconf_fragment_add]: added fragment {L, '/usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu'} to list @0x561c35dca9e8
libpkgconf/fragment.c:147 [pkgconf_fragment_add]: added fragment {l, 'glib-2.0'} to list @0x561c35dca9e8
libpkgconf/fragment.c:676 [pkgconf_fragment_parse]: post-subst: [-lm -pthread] -> [-lm -pthread]
libpkgconf/fragment.c:147 [pkgconf_fragment_add]: added fragment {l, 'm'} to list @0x561c35dcaa00
libpkgconf/fragment.c:196 [pkgconf_fragment_add]: created special fragment {'-pthread'} in list @0x561c35dcaa00
libpkgconf/tuple.c:296 [pkgconf_tuple_parse]: lookup tuple includedir
libpkgconf/tuple.c:296 [pkgconf_tuple_parse]: lookup tuple libdir
libpkgconf/fragment.c:676 [pkgconf_fragment_parse]: post-subst: [-I${includedir}/glib-2.0 -I${libdir}/glib-2.0/include] -> [-I/usr/local/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include]
libpkgconf/fragment.c:147 [pkgconf_fragment_add]: added fragment {I, '/usr/local/include/glib-2.0'} to list @0x561c35dcaa18
libpkgconf/fragment.c:147 [pkgconf_fragment_add]: added fragment {I, '/usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include'} to list @0x561c35dcaa18
libpkgconf/dependency.c:115 [add_or_replace_dependency_node]: added dependency [glib-2.0 = 2.76.3] to list @0x561c35dcaa90; flags=0
libpkgconf/pkg.c:531 [pkgconf_pkg_ref]: refcount@0x561c35dca990: 1
libpkgconf/pkg.c:531 [pkgconf_pkg_ref]: refcount@0x561c35dca990: 2
libpkgconf/cache.c:87 [pkgconf_cache_add]: added @0x561c35dca990 to cache
libpkgconf/pkg.c:531 [pkgconf_pkg_ref]: refcount@0x561c35dca990: 3
libpkgconf/pkg.c:1562 [pkgconf_pkg_traverse]: glib-2.0: level 1999
libpkgconf/pkg.c:1577 [pkgconf_pkg_traverse]: glib-2.0: walking requires list
libpkgconf/pkg.c:554 [pkgconf_pkg_unref]: refcount@0x561c35dca990: 2
libpkgconf/pkg.c:554 [pkgconf_pkg_unref]: refcount@0x561c35dca990: 1
libpkgconf/dependency.c:115 [add_or_replace_dependency_node]: added dependency [glib-2.0] to list @0x7fff61922eb8; flags=0
libpkgconf/pkg.c:1562 [pkgconf_pkg_traverse]: virtual:world: level 2000
libpkgconf/pkg.c:1577 [pkgconf_pkg_traverse]: virtual:world: walking requires list
libpkgconf/pkg.c:1343 [pkgconf_pkg_verify_dependency]: trying to verify dependency: glib-2.0
libpkgconf/pkg.c:730 [pkgconf_pkg_find]: looking for: glib-2.0
libpkgconf/cache.c:57 [pkgconf_cache_lookup]: found: glib-2.0 @0x561c35dca990
libpkgconf/pkg.c:531 [pkgconf_pkg_ref]: refcount@0x561c35dca990: 2
libpkgconf/pkg.c:762 [pkgconf_pkg_find]: glib-2.0 is cached
libpkgconf/pkg.c:531 [pkgconf_pkg_ref]: refcount@0x561c35dca990: 3
libpkgconf/pkg.c:1562 [pkgconf_pkg_traverse]: glib-2.0: level 1999
libpkgconf/pkg.c:1577 [pkgconf_pkg_traverse]: glib-2.0: walking requires list
libpkgconf/pkg.c:554 [pkgconf_pkg_unref]: refcount@0x561c35dca990: 2
2.76.3
libpkgconf/pkg.c:554 [pkgconf_pkg_unref]: refcount@0x561c35dca990: 1
libpkgconf/client.c:180 [pkgconf_client_deinit]: deinit @0x561c341b8820
libpkgconf/pkg.c:554 [pkgconf_pkg_unref]: refcount@0x561c35dca990: 0
libpkgconf/cache.c:113 [pkgconf_cache_remove]: removed @0x561c35dca990 from cache
libpkgconf/cache.c:142 [pkgconf_cache_free]: cleared package cache
```

```
sudo medit /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/glib-2.0.pc
prefix=/usr/local
includedir=${prefix}/include
libdir=${prefix}/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu

bindir=${prefix}/bin
glib_genmarshal=${bindir}/glib-genmarshal
gobject_query=${bindir}/gobject-query
glib_mkenums=${bindir}/glib-mkenums

Name: GLib
Description: C Utility Library
Version: 2.76.3
Requires.private: libpcre2-8 >= 10.32
Libs: -L${libdir} -lglib-2.0
Libs.private: -lm -pthread
Cflags: -I${includedir}/glib-2.0 -I${libdir}/glib-2.0/include
```

```
locate glib-2.0.pc
/usr/lib/pkgconfig/dbus-sharp-glib-2.0.pc
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/glib-2.0.pc
/usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/glib-2.0.pc
```

```
sudo medit /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/glib-2.0.pc
prefix=/usr
includedir=${prefix}/include
libdir=${prefix}/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu

bindir=${prefix}/bin
glib_genmarshal=${bindir}/glib-genmarshal
gobject_query=${bindir}/gobject-query
glib_mkenums=${bindir}/glib-mkenums

Name: GLib
Description: C Utility Library
Version: 2.74.6
Requires.private: libpcre2-8 >=  10.32
Libs: -L${libdir} -lglib-2.0
Libs.private: -pthread -lm
Cflags: -I${includedir}/glib-2.0 -I${libdir}/glib-2.0/include
```

Comment: "downloaded the latest version" : How have you installed v2.76.3 ? Please add to your post the outputs of `locate glib-2.0.pc` and `pkg-config --debug --modversion glib-2.0`.

Comment: @harrymc added required info.

Answer (score 0):

I thank very much Debian developers that helpt me to fix the mess that I had in my system.

What happened:
Using `apt policy`, it was found that existed many differend linux distributions. I didnt know that this can create problems. I had ubuntu, debian olds, and debian bookworm.

- 1st step: Remove all distributions that i didnt want and keep only one in
  source list  `/etc/apt/sources.list`.
- 2nd step: Delete in /user/local/ all folders/ files related to *gvfs* *glib*
- 3rd step: `apt update` `apt upgrade` `apt disto-upgrade` `apt full-upgrade`
- 4th step: `apt-get install -f -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-overwrite" PACKAGENAME` if you have dpkg error problems. Please keep records of overwritten files.

Thanks (linux) Debian developers! Keep open source good work! :)